# Is it possible to load different parts (not everything ) of a model on demand when using autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have integrated the autodesk forge viewer and can show design files(model) using it. Now I want to restrict the model data to be showed according to the roles of the user. For example, show only the engineering parts to the engineers and so on. I can hide elements but if a user want to see all elements, they can. This needs to be restricted. So, when the viewer is initialized with the model data, only the necessary data will be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can do it through the following steps:

1. save all dbid you want to show
2. add it through `options` parameter of method

```
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, {
      ids:[16168,12247,...]
    })
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Great answer Paxton. For more info, check out this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only.